# Can I add the gain feature importance metric for multiple features from XGBoost?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, boosting, importance

I would like to combine the "gain" feature importance metric from multiple features since this is potentially more informative. In my example, I would like to compare the importance of both hands (i.e., combine two features) to the importance of the neck, nose, etc. How do I combine the gain feature importance metric across multiple features?

Below are the individual (top) and cleaner, more informative combined (bottom) feature importance plots. Here, the combined “gain” is the **sum** of individual gains. Notice that the "Nose" is relatively important in the top plot but not the bottom plot.

My interpretation is that the distal joints are more important for prediction than the proximal joints, and that the nose and neck are the least important features for my classification task. Is this interpretation correct?

[image]
[image]

Comment: This related [post for random forest models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/311488/summing-feature-importance-in-scikit-learn-for-a-set-of-features) explains why summing feature importance is appropriate. I think XGBoost Gain is calculated similarly, so I will proceed with summing feature importance. Thanks