# How Gini importance works

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, random-forest

I have searched for how feature importance in random forest works, but I could not understand. Can anyone explain how it works?.

How random forest selects feature importance by Gini?

Comment: This question was answered here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92419/relative-importance-of-a-set-of-predictors-in-a-random-forests-classification-in so I think we can consider this a duplicate question